# How to disable PHPMailer redirect

Tags: php, forms, email, submit, phpmailer

I have mail form:

```
  <div class="contact">
    <form id="mailer-form" action="./plugins/mailer/gmail.php" method="post" name="message">
      <input type="text" name="name" /> <span>Jméno <strong>*</strong></span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input type="text" name="email" /> <span>Email <strong>*</strong></span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input type="text" name="subject" /> <span>Předmět</span>
      <input type="hidden" name="frompage" value="yes" />
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <span>Zpráva <strong> * </strong></span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Odeslat zprávu!" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

And PHPMailer script:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST['frompage'] == "yes")
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    require './PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "xxx";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "xxx";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('xxx', 'xxx');

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('xxx', 'xxx');

    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $mail->msgHTML($_POST['message']);

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

Sending email works fine but after sending email the page redirects me to the gmail.php with Message sent echo.

How can I disable it beacuse of staying on the index.php with response in value of the submit button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not redirecting you, you set the form action to "./plugins/mailer/gmail.php", that's where your form data gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
echo "Message sent!";
```

by

```
header("Location:YourFormPage.php");
```

It will send you back. It's possible to do what your looking for, you need to research about AJAX so using this will not be necessary to leave the first page and complete the form submition.